# Elegant approach to fetch the first value from each group without using outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I am trying to fetch the first value from each of the groups in my data. However I don't like to use the outer query/with clause. Can you let me know how can I write this in a elegant way without using outer query?

I have used outer query to fetch the first value from each group. However, Can you please help me write this in elegant manner within the same sql. Is there any function like Max, Min that will give us the first value so that I don't have to write this outer query

```
select * 
from (    
  select subject_id,hadm_id,
         rank() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id ORDER BY row_id) AS BG_CG_number 
  from labevents
  where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') 
    AND valuenum > 110 
    and hadm_id is not null
) t1 
where t1.bg_cg_number = 1
```

Please find the screenshot below for current and expected output
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the sub-query?

Comment: Is there any other way to write this? Like Max, Min function which can help us get the first_value? Want to know is there any other easy/elegant way to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the derived table (aka sub-query).

Postgres' proprietary `distinct on ()` will achieve the same and is usually faster than using a window function (that's not because of the derived table, but because of the window function):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

> `SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] )` keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). 
> Note that the “first row” of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first.

So you query can be rewritten to:

```
select distinct on (subject_id) subject_id, hadm_id
from labevents
where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') 
  AND valuenum > 110 
  and hadm_id is not null
order by subject_id, row_id;
```

Comment: Is there any difference between "distinct" and "distinct on"? I can use distinct to get one unique row for each subject as well. Right?

Comment: @SELVA: `distinct` operates on all columns in the select list, `distinct on (..)`  only on those specified.

Comment: Okay. But when we can use distinct and distinct on, to get 1st row easily, why do we have to use Rank() function? Is Rank() function used when we want to fetch records of a specific rank? What's the advantage of using Rank() over these two distinct and distinct on methods?

Comment: If my objective is fetch 1st record from each group, would you recommend me to use distinct/distinct on (based on my col conditions) over rank(),dense rank()

Comment: Can help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964182/how-to-skip-errors-while-defining-constraint-after-data-upload-postgresql